# How to convert float to int using dtype in read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with 5 columns.

```
Id           Origin      Space       Empl1       Empl2
11084676.0   0.0         0.0         0.0         NaN
11084654.0   0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
11084591.0   0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

Since the file is large, I want to avoid a default assignment of types. Therefore, I want to assign the following types to columns:

```
Id        int
Origin    str
Space     str
Empl1     str
Empl2     str
```

This is how I do it:

```
columns = ["Id", "Origin", "Space", "Empl1", "Empl2"]
types = ["int", "str", "str", "str", "str"]

df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=';', header=0, dtype=dict(zip(columns, types)), usecols=columns, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
```

But the problem is that the columns `Id` contains float value:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32')
>   according to the rule 'safe'

Is there anyway to force the conversion according to the specified data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to cast a type to "Id" afterwards, e.g.

```
df['Id'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Id'], downcast='unsigned', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Remove the 'Id' key for the dictionary, if you want to avoid casting on it.
`types_dct = dict(zip(columns, types))
del types_dict['Id']`

Comment: This lines produces an error `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity`. Do you know what it may indicate?

Comment: These are two lines actually
`types_dct = dict(zip(columns, types))` 
`del types_dict['Id']`
`df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=';', header=0, dtype=types_dict, usecols=columns, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
`

Answer (score 0):

These are two lines actually

```
types_dct = dict(zip(columns, types))
del types_dict['Id']
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=';', header=0, dtype=types_dict, usecols=columns, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
```